# How can I get powershell to write þ (lowercase thorn) to a file as 0xfe?

Tags: powershell, io, special-characters, extended-ascii

I am attempting to write a PS script that builds and executes a script file for Rocket Software's SBClient. The scripting language uses two different delimiters, þ (lowercase thorn) (0xFE) and ü (u with umlaut) (0xFC).

Each of these gets written to files as two characters. þ is written as Ã¾ (A with tilde and 3/4) (0xC3 0xBE). ü gets written as Ã¼ (A with tilde and 1/4) (0xC3 0xBC).

I have tried multiple different methods to write the file and it comes up the same way every time. I'm sure this is because these are extended ASCII characters.

Is there a way to write these to a text file with their proper two-character hex codes without converting the string to hex and writing a binary file? If not, what is the best way to convert the string to hex for this? I have seen a few different examples in other languages, but nothing really solid in PS.

It looks like I could convert the string to an array of bytes and then use `io.file::WriteAllBytes()` to write the file. I was just hoping there was a better way to do this.

Here is the pertinent code...

```
$ScriptFileContent = 'TUSCRIPTþþþ[Company Name] Logon Please:þ{enter}üPST{enter}þ2þ'
$ScriptFilePath = ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("ApplicationData")).ToString() + "\Rocket Software\SBClient\tuscript\NT"
out-file -filepath $ScriptFilePath -inputobject $ScriptFileContent -encoding ascii
```

**Solution**

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
$ScriptFileContent = 'TUSCRIPTþþþ[Company Name] Logon Please:þ{enter}üPST{enter}þ2þ'
$ScriptFileContent = $enc.GetBytes($ScriptFileContent)
$ScriptFilePath = ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("ApplicationData")).ToString() + "\Rocket Software\SBClient\tuscript\NT"
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($ScriptFilePath, $ScriptFileContent)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far, code-wise?

Comment: Different approaches include the following:
`out-file`, specifying the encoding
`Add-Content`
.Net's StreamWriter

There may have been more others. All of them write the characters as explained above. I really thought that `out-file` would do it with at least one of the encoding options.

Comment: Havent had many encoding issues but when I do this `[char]0xFC | Out-File -Encoding unicode c:\temp\temp.txt` the charater appears correctly in Notepad++

Comment: Matt, take a look at it in a hex editor or with the HEX-Editor plugin for npp. It probably didn't write it as FC.

Comment: Tried to fix the formatting for you

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. I just found the formatting buttons. I'm not sure why simply adding four spaces before each line didn't do the trick.

Comment: Its because the line above it, _Here is the pertinent code..._,  did not. I added a newline to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing are your chars, outside ASCII, being encoded as UTF-8. You have two choices here:

- either you use `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` to write your file as Latin1
- or you use the `FileStream.WriteByte()` method of the result of `io.file.Open` to directly write the `0xFE` and `0xFC` bytes yourself (seems less overkill, but that depends how you write the rest of the data)

Comment: I like the first option. I'm pretty new to PS. How would I use that with `out-file` or with `Add-Content`?

Comment: You'll need to post a bit of your current code if you want us to provide a concrete answer.